# Can't get text input from Tkinter Text widget into sqlite3 database

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter, text-widget

trying to get text input from a tkinter Text widget with variable name sponsor with the following command

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(tables.db)

cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sponsors` (sponsor_id  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, sponsor TEXT)")
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO 'sponsors' (sponsor) VALUES(?)", sponsor.get('1.0', 'end'))

conn.commit()
```

I typed in "**Vector Linkz Limited**" to be inserted into the sponsors table in the sqlite Database but gut the following error

> cursor.execute("INSERT INTO 'sponsors' (sponsor) VALUES(?)", sponsor.get('1.0', 'end'))
> sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 21 supplied.

I don't even know what this means to be honest, can anyone help me out please. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument of `cursor.execute(...)` is expected to be a tuple or list, so change

```py
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO 'sponsors' (sponsor) VALUES(?)", sponsor.get('1.0', 'end'))
```

to

```py
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO 'sponsors' (sponsor) VALUES(?)", [sponsor.get('1.0', 'end')])
```